# Passing edited value of data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am using a jquery data table in which I am inserting values from the database. I want to edit the same data and post it further to update the database. But at the time of posting the original values of the fields from DB are posted and not the edited one. How Should i do it.

```
<tr>
<td>
    <input type=checkbox name='delBox' value='$data[0]' id='delBox'>
</td>
<td>$pid</td>
<td contenteditable='true'>$project_name</td>
<td contenteditable='true'>$variant_no</td>
</tr>
```

now on selection of ckeckbox i need to edit the value and pass it to database. but at the time of parsing the chaged $project_name doesnot go.please hepl what can i do to edit values.

Comment: can you add your code to the question?

Comment: What exactly are you using to communicate with the database (Ruby, PHP, just Ajax etc.)